# service, that listens for Location Service

Tags: android

So, I was asked to make a Location Tracker.
Location tracker should track even if the app is tuned off...
My idea is to start my own service (lets call it TrackingService) from the activity by calling startService(intent); so the service will run forever (I guess..) and then connect to Location Service from my own created TrackingService. TrackingService should listen to location changes after app was turned off.
I write some code, started TrackingService,  and requested location updates in a new thread.
Anyway, location updates stops after I quit app but service is still running.

EDIT:
Ok, so i manage to improve my code a bit, so now when my app is running, i get Log's that my thread (that runs in separate service) is running and that it receives Location Updates.
When i quit y app I still get Log that my thread is running but it does not receives Location Updates...
Anyone can point my a reason why?
P.S. I know that probably there are better ways to get the job done, but I really hoping to fix my code.
Here goes service class

```
    public class TrackingService extends Service {
// DEBUG
public final static String TAG = "TrackingService";
public final static boolean D = true;
 // Global constants
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000;  // Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 4000;  // A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds    
//
int mStartMode;       // indicates how to behave if the service is killed
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();      // interface for clients that bind
boolean mAllowRebind; // indicates whether onRebind should be used
private int number; // testavimui
LocationThread mLocationThread;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onCreated started");};
    mLocationThread = new LocationThread(this); 
    mLocationThread.start();
   // mLocationThread.run();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onStartCommand started");};
    // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
    return mStartMode;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onBind started");};
    // A client is binding to the service with bindService()
    return mBinder;
}
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onUnBind started");};
    // All clients have unbound with unbindService()
    return mAllowRebind;
}
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onReBind started");};
    // A client is binding to the service with bindService(),
    // after onUnbind() has already been called
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "service - onDestroy started");};
    // The service is no longer used and is being destroyed
    mLocationThread.cancel();
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    TrackingService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return TrackingService.this;
    }
}

public int number(){
    number += 1;
    return number;
}



private class LocationThread extends Thread implements
                        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
                        LocationListener{ 


    private boolean keepOn;
    private Context mContext;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient; 
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public LocationThread (Context context){
        mContext = context;
        keepOn = true;

    }

    public void cancel() {
        keepOn = false;
        if (D){Log.d(TAG, "thread was canceled");};


    }

    public void run(){
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); // Use high accuracy 
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL); // Set the update interval to 5 seconds 
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL); // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(mContext, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();

        while (keepOn){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                if(D){Log.d(TAG, "thread running");};
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if(D){Log.d(TAG, "connection failed");};
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if(D){Log.d(TAG, "connected to location service");};
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        if(D){Log.d(TAG, "disconnected from location service");};
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(D){Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");};

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't quite get it, how do you expect it to behave? Do you mean it updates the first time your activity runs but not subsequent times?

Comment: I expect to update location and store it to PolylineOptions and pass PolylineOptions back to activity when it comes to life. But that is future task. right now i just need proof that location is updated when app is destroyed. I thing that my thread does not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation is not specific about it, I suggest you perform the call to `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` in the main (UI) thread. You can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to accomplish that if the call originates from a separate thread.

BTW, if you want your service to run in a separate thread, I suggest you extend [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and override the `onHandleIntent()` method, it is easier that way.

**Further advice:**

If you want your `Service` to run even when the phone is in sleep mode, you need a wake lock.

Hint: You don't have to make it run continuosly, that will consume a lot of battery needlessly. Make your `Service`collect a single location, save it to a local database or deliver it to a bound activity and then stop, and then schedule that `Service` to run from time to time using `AlarmManager`.

It goes like this: `AlarmManager` calls a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, which by its turn calls your `Service`.

I suggest you read the [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) documentation, it will provide a wake lock for your service automatically (which you have to manually release before the service stops).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will consider this in the future, but right now I don't really care about short battery life :)
I think my Thread dos not run properly.